# How to send UIImage Extension as parameter to server using Alamofire ppost request in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, postman, alamofire

I have a postman api that requires an Extension to send with the image. Without the extension it take the image as a file. Help me to send the image with the extension or tell me the better way to do so, or let me know where i am doing wrong.[Postman Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvwbE.png)  Here is my code so far:

```
func UPLOD(){
    guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accesstoken") else {
        return
    }
    print("Create button ACCESS KEY::::- \(token)")
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "x-access-token": token,
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Content-Disposition" : "form-data",
        "Filename" : "Angle",
        "Ext" : ".png"
    ]

    let image = myImageView.image
    let imgData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)!
    

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "FileToUpload", fileName: "swift_file.png", mimeType: "image/png")

        print("mutlipart 1st \(multipartFormData)")

        multipartFormData.append("angela".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"Filename")
        multipartFormData.append("Image".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"Folder")
        //multipartFormData.append("jpeg".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"Ext")
        //multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "Ext", mimeType: "image/png")

        }, to:"http://192.168.80.21:8800/api/v1/upload/uploadfile", method:.post, headers:headers)
        {
        (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                print("x:::::::::\(result)")
                print("Upload;;\(upload)")
                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                        print("Upload Progress: \(progress)")
                    })
                upload.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        guard response.error == nil else {
                            print("Pre json\(response as Any)")
                            let json = JSON(response)
                            print("JSON: \(json)")
                            return
                        }
                        print(response.result.value as Any)
                        print("Response:     \(JSON(response.data as Any))")
                    }
        
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to solve that?

Comment: Did all that but api not receiving any extension

Comment: Error code -1001